# Ruby: how to combine puts and return inside if condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I print a message and then return from a function in ruby?

```
2.3.4 :038 > def foo(num)
2.3.4 :039?>   print "Your number is: #{num}" && return if num > 10
2.3.4 :040?>   print "Number too small"
2.3.4 :041?>   end
 => :foo
2.3.4 :042 > foo(47)
 => nil
2.3.4 :043 > foo(7)
Number too small => nil
2.3.4 :044 >
```

When I called foo with `47` why didn't I got `Your number is: 47` in output?

PS: This function can be written in other simpler ways also, I just wanted to express my doubt via this function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Ruby reads this line

```
print "Your number is: #{num}" && return if num > 10
```

like this

```
print("Your number is: #{num}" && return) if num > 10
```

That leads the method to `return` before it had the chance to `print` anything.

Adding a pair of parenthesis helps Ruby to resolve the desired order:

```
print("Your number is: #{num}") || return if num > 10
```

Comment: I had to change `&&` to `||` because print was returning nil.

Answer (score 4):

You have a precedence issue which can be fixed using parentheses. But since you are trying to express a control flow, you should use the control flow operators `and` and `or` instead of the boolean operators `&&` and `||`.

The idiom works like this: (just examples, it's not limited to `return` and `fail`)

```
do_something and return "it worked"
```

or:

```
do_something or fail "it didn't work"
```

It allows you to evaluate a second expression depending on whether the first expression succeeded or not. `do_something` is supposed to return a truthy value in case of success and a falsey value in case of failure.

`print` however always returns `nil`, so it doesn't work as expected in this regard. You would have to reverse the logic:

```
print "Your number is: #{num}" or return
```

But this doesn't read naturally any more, does it? Beside, `return` is always invoked, because `print` will never return a truthy value. You actually want:

```
print "Your number is: #{num}"
return
```

I would therefore simply write:

```
def foo(num)
  if num > 10
    puts "Your number is: #{num}"
  else
    puts "Number too small"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def foo(num)
   puts(num > 10 ? "Your number is: #{num}" : "Number too small")
end
```

I think this is the cleaner way to do that, with an If ternary. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Since `print` (and `puts`) returns `nil`, this works just as well:

```
def foo(num)
  return print "Your number is: #{num}" if num > 10
  print "Number too small"
end
```

And to show clearer intention, place the [guard clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)) first:

```
def foo(num)
  return print "Number too small" if num <= 10
  print "Your number is: #{num}"
end
```

Examples:

```
> foo 47
Your number is: 47=> nil
> foo 7
Number too small=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
def foo(num)
  print case num
        when -Float::INFINITY...10 then "Number too small"
        else "Your number is: #{num}"
        end
end
```

Comment: I would have expected `when 10.method(:>).to_proc` in your answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do one line if statements is with `;`

```
def foo(num)
  if num < 10; print "Your number is: #{num}" && return; end
  print "Number too small"
end
```